# Array / objects - getting object by id returning all the data

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some data that looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "item":{
         "Name":"Name1",
         "working":true,
         "extra":{
            "active":true
         }
      },
      "id":2
   },
   {
      "item":{
         "Name":"Name2",
         "working":true,
         "extra":{
            "active":true
         }
      },
      "id":4
   }
]
```

I also have the 'id' that I need.

So basically I need to get the object which contains the id required.

I'm trying this:

```
const item = myDat.find(item => item.id === '4');

console.log(item); // returns all the data and not the one I need
```

It's currently giving me all the data and not the object I need.

How can I fix this?

Comment: but shouldnt it return undefined since there is no element with string id 4

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: [it returns `undefined`](https://jsbin.com/lotifal/1/edit?js,console). And if you do a proper check for a number: [it returns a single object](https://jsbin.com/xehiber/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code can't find the item because you are comparing 4 === "4" which are different. one is string the other one is number.

const item = myDat.find(item => item.id === '4');

change this to

```
const item = myDat.find(item => item.id === 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first issue that I see is that the `id` field is type `number`, but you are comparing it with a `string` (`'4'`). You should compare it like: `item.id === 4`.

Secondly, find returns either an item or `undefined` (see them [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)), therefore, I do not understand how does it return all data.

Comment: It's funny you said that as since I've changed it to number I now get an error undefined. In the console.log the data is shown with [0].... [1].... etc - Should I not need a for loop?

Comment: The `filter` itself is a loop. Are you sure that the structure is the one that you have posted?

Comment: It can't find id? But when I do this: console.log(myDat[0].id); or console.log(myDat[1].id); it displays the id ... with the filter I get undefined

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Change `myDat.find(item => item.id === '4')` to `myDat.find(item => item.id === 4)`

Comment: stackoverflow allows snippets. you could put this as one